# How to MS Bot Framework VideoCard jump to timeline

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards

How to play video starting from a specific time when my user click on the timeline links. Pasted below is the videocard displayed in my chat window.(Not on an html/webpage)

[image]

I have my videocard like the following to be shown as response to chat message

```
public Attachment GetVideoCard()
    {
        var videoId = "38ef226cb5";
        var videoCard = new VideoCard
        {
            Title = "Oil and Gas Industry Basics",
            Subtitle = "by abcd",
            Text = "In this Oil and Gas Industry Overview, we discuss the history of oil and gas production, three sectors of the industry—upstream, midstream, and downstream, geologic formations, types of oil and gas wells, and the makeup of a well stream.",
            Image = new ThumbnailUrl
            {
                Url = "someimage.png"
            },
            Media = new List<MediaUrl>
    {
        new MediaUrl()
        {
            Url =$"https://youtu.be/O-qiUD9TEtQ"
           
        }
    },
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>
    {
        new CardAction()
        {
            Title = "Learn More",
            Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
            Value = "https://peach.blender.org/"
        }
    }
        };

        return videoCard.ToAttachment();
    }
```

When my chatbot users click on the timeline, how can I start my videocard to start playing video from the specific timeline links they clicked?

The above use case i mentioned is for a video from youtube.
How the above videoCard will work if the video is from the videos from MSstreams ?
Any helpful samples or documents ?

Note: I do not want to jump to open YouTube to play the video, but prefer to play the video time from within the chat bot adaptivecard/videocard.

Comment: What is the client you are using? The answer will largely be dependent on what the client is and its capabilities, not the bot.

Comment: I am using MS bot framework v4. and the videos,  we want to show are from MS Streams, some stored in SharePoint locations, some from YouTube, some videos are from azure blob storage, and other from OneDrive

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the client you intend the user to use for connecting to your bot with. While you can normally specify a time frame in the video thru the URL (e.g. `https://somevideo.youtube.com?t=60` which would start the video at the one minute mark), doing so in BotFramework via a video card ignores the time parameter.

But, if you can manipulate the video URL thru the client, then it's possible you could achieve this. For instance, if you are using [BotFramework Web Chat](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-webchat), as the activity passes into Web Chat's store, the time parameter could potentially be appended to the URL before it is rendered in the chat. Thus, the video would then start at a particular time.

The short of it is, you will need to research the client(s) you intend to work with to determine what options you have.